# POSTDATA without buttons in HTML4?

Tags: html, image, graphing, postdata

I have graphs in an html page.  The graphs are generated by a call to a cgi-bin program in an IMG tag:
     <IMG src="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/StatBarChart.cgi?data=1,2,&data=3,5,1&legend=EC,ER">
Currently, the data for the graphs is passed as GET args (in the URL itself.)

Everything’s working OK, but te GET arguments are too long. I want to pass the data via POSTDATA.  All the books I have (and discussions on the web that I’ve found) talk about using POSTDATA in forms that include a Submit button.  I just want the graphs to appear as part of the page, without a Submit.  Can this be done?  Can it be done in HTML4, or does it require javascript?

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite to make urls shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I would require javascript, as you would have to get the resource yourself and set it to the img tag. This is not possible in html4.

Also, I don't see the problem with a long url. Your user will never see it (unless he looks in the sourcecode, which I don't consider as simple "user" anymore) so there is no problem with that either.

Comment: Microsoft IE has a maximum URL length of 2,083 characters, according to http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q208427 .  Some of my graphs are pushing that limit.

Comment: bah, violating the Zero, One, Infinity principle. You won't get around ajavascript then.